# SQL Columns as rows join, PIVOT?

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot, rows

I tried working with the results i found on here using the pivot answers but i'm not getting it to work. I am trying to join the columns in one table to the rows in another table by date.

I have the following table structure/results.

Holidays table

> Date | SusanCalladine |    ClaireWillis |  FazailaPirbhai
>   2016-08-22 |   0 | 0 | 1
>   2016-08-23 |   0 | 1 | 1
>   2016-08-24 |   0 | 1 | 1
>   2016-08-25 |   0 | 1 | 1
>   2016-08-26 |   0 | 0 | 1

Which i am trying to join on date and row to the following (each date has 3 people in seperate rows)

Telephony Table

> CallDate | AgentName | InboundCallsAnswered |  InboundHandleTime
>   2016-08-22 |   Claire Willis | 0 | 0
>   2016-08-22 |   Fazaila Pirbhai |   36 |    17484
>   2016-08-22 |   Susan Calladine |   0 | 0
>   2016-08-23 |   Claire Willis | 12 |    4250
>   2016-08-23 |   Fazaila Pirbhai |   16 |    23360
>   2016-08-23 |   Susan Calladine |   0 | 0

any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want. if not do let me know

```
CREATE TABLE  ##Holidaystable
([Date] DATE, SusanCalladine INT, ClaireWillis INT, FazailaPirbhai INT);

INSERT INTO ##Holidaystable VALUES
('2016-08-22',  0, 0, 1),
('2016-08-23',  0, 1, 1),
('2016-08-24',  0, 1, 1),
('2016-08-25', 0, 1, 1),
('2016-08-26',  0, 0, 1)



CREATE TABLE  ##TelephonyTable
([CallDate] DATE, AgentName VARCHAR(50), InboundCallsAnswered INT, InboundHandleTime INT);
INSERT INTO ##TelephonyTable VALUES
('2016-08-22' , 'Claire Willis' , 0 , 0),
('2016-08-22' , 'Fazaila Pirbhai' , 36 , 17484),
('2016-08-22' , 'Susan Calladine' , 0 , 0),
('2016-08-23' , 'Claire Willis' , 12 , 4250),
('2016-08-23' , 'Fazaila Pirbhai' , 16 , 23360),
('2016-08-23' , 'Susan Calladine' , 0 , 0)

----Use a CTE for the query as below
;WITH Holiday AS
(SELECT 
H.[Date],
T.CallDate 
--,T.*
FROM ##Holidaystable H
INNER JOIN  ##TelephonyTable T
ON H.[Date]=T.CallDate
)
SELECT * FROM Holiday
PIVOT
(
COUNT([Date]) FOR CallDate IN ([2016-08-22],[2016-08-23])
) AS PV1
```

Comment: thanks for the help JonWay, it's getting closer to what i need, basically in the holidays table i need to sum the different values for each person and align that to the telephony table and same again, sum the values in that table for each person, there are 3 people in each table but they are rows in one table and columns in the other table, years worth of dates etc

Comment: In that Case @Yared  answer will work fine if you unpivot the Holiday Table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` to make rows from columns in Holiday table and join the result with Telephony by `Date` and `AgentName` columns.

```
-- CREATE Holiday Table
CREATE TABLE Holiday
    (
      Date DATE NOT NULL ,
      [Susan Calladine] INT NULL ,
      [Claire Willis] INT NULL ,
      [Fazaila Pirbhai] INT NULL
    );

-- CREATE Telephony Table
CREATE TABLE Telephony
    (
      CallDate DATE NOT NULL ,
      AgentName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
      InboundCallsAnswered INT NULL ,
      InboundHandleTime INT NULL
    );

-- Insert rows in Holiday
INSERT  INTO Holiday
VALUES  ( '2016-08-22', 0, 0, 1 ),
        ( '2016-08-23', 0, 1, 1 ),
        ( '2016-08-24', 0, 1, 1 ),
        ( '2016-08-25', 0, 1, 1 ),
        ( '2016-08-26', 0, 0, 1 );

-- Insert rows in Telephony
INSERT  INTO Telephony
VALUES  ( '2016-08-22', 'Claire Willis', 0, 0 ),
        ( '2016-08-22', 'Fazaila Pirbhai', 36, 17484 ),
        ( '2016-08-22', 'Susan Calladine', 0, 0 ),
        ( '2016-08-23', 'Claire Willis', 12, 4250 ),
        ( '2016-08-23', 'Fazaila Pirbhai', 16, 23360 ),
        ( '2016-08-23', 'Susan Calladine', 0, 0 );


-- Use UNPIVOT
WITH    Hol
          AS ( SELECT   Date ,
                        AgentName ,
                        Calls
               FROM     ( SELECT    *
                          FROM      Holiday
                        ) p UNPIVOT ( Calls FOR AgentName IN ( [Susan Calladine],
                                                              [Claire Willis],
                                                              [Fazaila Pirbhai] ) ) AS unpvt
             )
    SELECT  Date ,
            Hol.AgentName ,
            Calls ,
            InboundCallsAnswered ,
            InboundHandleTime
    FROM    Hol
            LEFT JOIN Telephony t ON Hol.Date = t.CallDate
                                     AND Hol.AgentName = t.AgentName
    ORDER BY Date ,
            AgentName;
```

The result will be :

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yared!! that's spot on

Comment: w00t, Glad you got what you wanted